# Get the index of newly inserted record with array unshift

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

If I use array.push everything works fine, but when I push the currently inserted element to the top of the list, I cannot access the index of the elements for styling.

cmp:

```
 <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="sObject[]" />


    <lightning:button  label="desc" title="desc" onclick="{! c.postdescription}" class="slds-float_right"/>


     <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account" indexVar="accountwrapper">
       <div class="slds-size_1-of-1">
           <div class="slds-text-align_left slds-m-around_x-small" ><pre class="preclass"  aura:id="preclassId"><ui:outputText  class = "" value="{!account.Description}"/></pre></div>
           <a href="" onclick="{!c.removeCSS}" aura:id="expand" value="{!accountwrapper}" id="{!account.Id}"  data-index="{!accountwrapper}" data-record="{!account}" >see more</a>    
           <div class="slds-size_1-of-1">
         <div class="slds-border_bottom slds-m-around_x-small"></div>
          </div>   
      </div>
```

JS:

```
//On doinit I'm adding list of accounts to accounts attribute.


    postdescription: function(component,event){
     var action = component.get("c.insertaccountDesc");
            action.setParams({
                "comment": commentvalue,
            });


       action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

         if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
             var accountslist = response.getReturnValue();
             var arr = component.get("v.accounts");
             arr.unshift( response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.accounts",arr);
        }

    var lnum = new Number('5');
    var hnum = new Number(arr[0].CommentBody.split("\n").length);
    if(lnum > hnum){
// this is where the element is undefined
     var expand1= component.find("expand")[0];
     var preclassindex = component.find("preclassId")[0];
     $A.util.removeClass(preclassindex, "preclass");
     $A.util.addClass(expand1, "slds-hide");
                        }

}
```

apex:

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account insertaccountDesc(String description){
        Account a = new Account();
        a.description= description;
        a.Id = recordId;
        insert a;
        return [SELECT Id,description FROM Account WHERE id=: a.id LIMIT 1][0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

aura:iteration does not render the elements until the next render cycle. Therefore, you can't do what you're trying to do until the next cycle, which you could do like this:

```
setTimeout($A.getCallback(function() {
  var expand1 = component.find("expand")[0];
  ...
}));
```

Comment: I did try the timeout, but the slds-hide doesn't work although now I see index of the newly inserted element as "0"

Comment: @cartman Make sure you're using slds (e.g. aura:application extends="force:slds"). It should definitely work if you're getting the element back from component.find.

Comment: I can see the description being added, so the component is rendered, but the style is not being applied.How do I identify the index of the current element? I'm assuming it to be 0 since I'm using unshift.

Comment: I tried looping through all the elements again, it just deosn't work for the new record.It is a component with in the community, I see the toggletext has a value in timeout "toggleText is SecureComponent: markup://aura:html {16:130;a} {expand}{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }". Not sure how to get the index of they styling element,I'm assuming it to be zero since I'm inserting it at the beginning of the array.

Comment: @cartman Honestly, it'd be easier to start with slds-hide on the element, then remove it when you click the toggle. This should remove the race condition you seem to be experiencing.

Comment: I just tried it and I'm experiencing the same thing, the slds-hide is not being removed.